# Search only get or set references for property in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I use VS 2010 and C#. When I want to found all references to the methods or properties I press <kbd>Shift+F12</kbd>. It's possible to find only get or set references for examined property.

It's possible? Maybe I should install any extension?

Comment: That'd be a nice extension to have too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to evalutate the [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) product which has extremely powerful features that enhance Visual Studio a lot.

[Find Usages](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Find_Usages) is what you are looking for.

If you find the ReSharper to be ok (and you will!) then go ahead and buy a license after evaluation.

Just make sure to try it out at least!

Comment: @Jacek OK, then I assume you are using Visual Studio Express as well since that one is free as well. If you on the other hand are using the commercial version then buying ReSharper would be a non-issue since the added value is worth it.

Comment: I use VS2010 Premium at work, but we will not buy software only for this feature.<br/> Now I install 30days trial, maybe it has other fine features

Comment: @Jacek It has **many** other fine features that I wouldn't want to be without. Powerful refactoring, on-the-fly code analysis and much more. Read this list of [features](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html).

Comment: I installed R#, it is really fine tool, you opened my eyes :) Additionally there is feature which I looked for :) You win this chalenge

Comment: @Jacek It really is great although it is not free. So will you press the bounty button on my answer?

Answer (score 9):

The poor man's way is to simply remove/comment-out either the getter or setter and recompile: all the errors will be your references. ;)

EDIT: Instead of deleting it (which could be invalid syntax), change the visibility of the particular get/set to private.

Comment: It's not nice solution. I have quite big solution with over 40 projects. Compilation take many time ...

Comment: Don't need to tell me that twice (153 projects here)

Comment: For those reading this now, you could also mark your property with the `[Obsolete]` attribute and look for the compiler _warnings_; might be easier than straight-up breaking your build and sifting through other unrelated errors.